# Setting up an editing suite

Tags: room

I am in the process of putting together a proposal for the institute where I work to build and redesign sound editing suites. We want to build 6 rooms to accommodate the computer, speakers and enough room to have the producer/director come in and view with the editor. We don't have a huge amount of space but we have an area whereby we can build 6 small isolate cubicles.

What I want to know is the best materials to use to sound proof the rooms and also create an adequate sweet spot for the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read this book myself because I'm not yet at the point of building my own studio, but from what I've heard, this is the book to get: [Home Recording Studio: Build it Like the Pros, by Gervais Rod](http://www.amazon.com/Home-Recording-Studio-Build-Like/dp/143545717X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1302625881&sr=8-1).

This may sound snooty, but try as much as possible to limit the involvement of any non-audio related persons in the design decision making.  You can get yourself into real trouble if you do stuff the wrong way (i.e. for the sake of saving some money).  The truth of it is that the monumental problems that nodes of 125Hz, 200Hz, 250Hz, 341Hz, 672Hz and 983Hz would cause *us* at the mix position, is a shrug of the shoulders to an operations manager.

You're going to have to build walls between walls, use double layers of drywall, and buy buckets and buckets of green-glue or quietglue, all of which makes doing it properly rather more expensive than just throwing up some two-by-fours and gypsum board and calling it a day.

In my recent experience:

The (otherwise very nice) guy who designed and commissioned the new "mix" rooms at my work is a broadcast technician.  This means that all of the rooms are beautifully set up with dual 29" computer monitors, RME ADI-4 DDs, multi-channel intercom systems, 8 channel data-routers, and video screens that route from and play extremely nicely with a TerraBlock.  To be honest, it's really quite wonderful.  Only problem is that the Terrablock and servers and everything loud is housed in a room that is right across the hall from and *shares a ventilation duct with our main recording booth*.

A step further, two of the mix rooms and the main recording booth also have perfectly vertical 4' x 6' windows in them.  In the case of the recording booth this window is *literally* right next to the readers sitting position.

The problems are not insurmountable, but depending on who is coming in to read for us on a given day, they can add at least an hour's worth of work to a project with a 6 hour turnaround time.

Answer (score 2):

maybe start here?

http://www.gearslutz.com/board/studio-building-acoustics/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not having the computers in the isolated rooms.  The sound in the rooms could  be much nicer if you keep all the computers in a rack in a seperate room and use extension cables to get speakers & monitors etc into the editing suites.

Comment: I agree but we do have silent cooling on them and some of the cpu's are iMAC's so they don't really make any noise


Comment: @oinkaudio- I give those iMac's three months of solid student use before they start making crazy noises.